# Print raw HTTP request in Flask or WSGI

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I am debugging a microcontroller I've built which is writing raw HTTP requests line by line.  I am using Flask for my backend and I would like to see the entire request as it appears in this format:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Content-length: 123
User-agent: blah
...
```

I know Flask is based on WSGI. Is there anyway to get this to work with Flask?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

With flask you have access to the request object which contains all the HTTP details:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print(request.headers)
```

Comment: This only prints the header, not `all the HTTP details` as specified. Using other properties of request also doesn't help (e.g. data, form, values, etc). To print the HTTP request in its entirety, wrapping around WSGI suggested in @martinpieters' answer is the way to go.

Comment: This is not the answer.

Answer (score 63):

Yes, Flask is a WSGI application, so it is trivial to wrap your app in an extra layer that logs the request:

```
import pprint

class LoggingMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self._app = app

    def __call__(self, env, resp):
        errorlog = env['wsgi.errors']
        pprint.pprint(('REQUEST', env), stream=errorlog)

        def log_response(status, headers, *args):
            pprint.pprint(('RESPONSE', status, headers), stream=errorlog)
            return resp(status, headers, *args)

        return self._app(env, log_response)
```

This defines a piece of middleware to wrap your Flask application in. The advantage is that it operates entirely independent of Flask, giving you unfiltered insight into what goes in and what comes out.

How you apply the middleware depends on the exact WSGI server you are using; see your WSGI server documentation.

When running Flask with the built-in server (`app.run()`), do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.wsgi_app = LoggingMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)
    app.run()
```

The little `app.wsgi_app` wrapping dance places the `LoggingMiddleware` around the Flask WSGI application.

The output goes to the `wsgi.error` stream; where that ends up again depends on your WSGI server; `mod_wsgi` puts this in the Apache error log for your site, the bundled Flask server prints this to `stderr`.

Comment: How can I get the content of the request for this solution as well?

Comment: @ArthurColombiniGusmão: are you sure you want to do that? The body is potentially very large. You also have to work with a *stream*, which is like a file that can only be read once, and then have to provide a new stream to the next WSGI component to replace it. `env['wsgi.input']` is the stream, you could perhaps copy the data to a [`tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile), do something with that file, then seek back to the start and set `env['input.stream']` to point to it.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn Pieters! It may be not the best option then. My goal was to create a canonical snippet to quickly wrap Flask applications with for easy debugging (in controlled environments). Sometimes it seems to be easier to debug code that interfaces with REST APIs by having a middleware like this, but possibly I'm missing on existing solutions.

Answer (score 34):

suppose if you want complete details,

### There is an another way

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    print request.__dict__
    #this prints all variables in `dict` format including `headers`
```

Comment: That's not gonna work. `headers` isn't even a key; there is `environ` key which contains a mix of a different things including headers, but certainly not the full original request.

Comment: actually this does seem to work. when i do `pprint.pformat(request.__dict__, depth=5))` after importing `pprint` I see `environ` as the first key printed out for me.

Answer (score 18):

Why not?

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def log_request():
    app.logger.debug("Request Headers %s", request.headers)
    return None

# The remaining application code.
```

I've used the headers but you can use the same aproach to print any request attribute. The docs are here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.

Also you need to setup FLASK_DEBUG=1 to Flask.logger.debug to work, what is nice since you can disable it in production.

Regards,

Answer (score 14):

you probably want something like

```
print(request.headers)
print(request.cookies)
print(request.data)
print(request.args)
print(request.form)
print(request.endpoint)
print(request.method)
print(request.remote_addr)
```

Comment: I like this answer because it uses only flask objects.  Very easy to understand and use.

Comment: `print(request.body)` and adding `try...except` may help lot.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't use flask but it is fairly simple to setup a [socket echo server](http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/socket/echoserver.html).

```
import socket

host = ''
port = 8888
backlog = 5
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(backlog)
while 1:
    client, address = s.accept()
    data = client.recv(size)
    if data:
        client.send(data)
    client.close()
```

Comment: One caveat: if client sends "Expect: 110-continue" header, one will not see complete HTTP communication... You should send '100 Continue' back to client and read again body of the request.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a logger i found this useful

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat

```
from pprint import pformat
import requests
log.debug(pformat(request.headers))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and didn't see the difference with repr(request.headers). Can you elaborate?